# How to handle the back stack with an Intro Activity that only appears once

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-navigation

My app currently has a Main activity that handles both a Launcher intent and a file open intent. I'd like to add an intro activity to appear before Main on the first run.

The Intro activity gives the user the option to either go to Main or to go to Activity C, *which should then treat Main as its parent activity*.

What is the correct approach to handling this?

1. Do I create a new root activity that either shows Intro or forwards
   the intent to Main?
2. Do I keep Main as the root activity and use it to launch the Intro if appropriate?
3. With either approach, how do I properly handle the back stack such that Main is treated as the root activity after the user leaves the Intro?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would choose the first one because introduction is only for first time run. In second time always the main activity(Choose Activity) take the decision for redirect to the activity C or stay continue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Well if you go with the first approach you can keep a bool value in the `SharedPreference` true if the users saw the intro and false if they didn't.
2. But if you take the second approach (Which i would go for) you start with the `MainActivity` then you check either a value or whatever you decide to display your intro then launch it i your condition passes, then go back to your `MainActivity` even if you want to launch `ActivityC` and launch it from there.

You can also remove the undesired `Activity` in this case the `IntroActivity` from the `Backstack` with either calling finish after you start the `MainActivity` or `ActivityC` which removes `IntroActivity` form the `Backstack`, which will work as you want if you have `MainActivity` as your root.

Answer (score 0):

You should code your app for the *most common case* and then construct the backstacks for all the other situations. I'm assuming the most common case is: the user runs the App (after the first run) and enters `MainActivity`.

From this, you can construct the other user-flows. A bit of *pseudocode*  with appropriate logic:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(...);

        // get the intent used to launch this activity to work out the logic
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // how were we launched:
        if (/*is first run? */) {
            // switch from MainActivity to IntroActivity
            startActivity(IntroActivity);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        else if ( /* was launched from intro and not going to ActivityC */ ) {
            // carry on as normal!
        }
        else if ( /* was launched from intro and going to ActivityC */ ) {
            // launch ActivityC (which will now have MainActivity as its parent)
            startActivity(ActivityC);
        }

        /* if we reach here, the user launched the app normally (the most
         common case) or we have been launched from Intro */
        ....
    }
}
```

Intro:

```
class IntroActivity extends Activity {

  public launchNextActivity(boolean gotoActivityC) {
        // whatever the user chooses, we return to MainActivity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.this);
        // tell MainActivity if we want to go to ActivityC
        i.putExtra("GOTO_ACTIVITY_C", gotoActivityC);

        // launch MainActivity and finish the Intro
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
  }
}
```

I'll leave it to you to replace the logic comments and fill in the rest.